# Multiple String Replace Based on Index

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I need to replace multiple sections of a string based on their indices.

```
$string  = '01234567890123456789';

$replacements = array(
    array(3, 2, 'test'),
    array(8, 2, 'haha')
);

$expected_result = '012test567haha0123456789';
```

Indices in `$replacements` are expected not to have overlaps.

I have been trying to write my own solution, split the original array into multiple pieces based on sections which needs to be replaced or not, and finally combine them:

```
echo str_replace_with_indices($string, $replacements);
// outputs the expected result '012test567haha0123456789'

function str_replace_with_indices ($string, $replacements) {
    $string_chars = str_split($string);

    $string_sections = array();
    $replacing = false;
    $section = 0;
    foreach($string_chars as $char_idx => $char) {
        if ($replacing != (($r_idx = replacing($replacements, $char_idx)) !== false)) {
            $replacing = !$replacing;
            $section++;
        }
        $string_sections[$section] = $string_sections[$section] ? $string_sections[$section] : array();
        $string_sections[$section]['original'] .= $char;
        if ($replacing) $string_sections[$section]['new'] = $replacements[$r_idx][2];
    }

    $string_result = '';
    foreach($string_sections as $s) {
        $string_result .= ($s['new']) ? $s['new'] : $s['original'];
    }

    return $string_result; 
}

function replacing($replacements, $idx) {
   foreach($replacements as $r_idx => $r) {
       if ($idx >= $r[0] && $idx < $r[0]+$r[1]) {
           return $r_idx;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Is there any more effective way to achieve the same result?

The above solution doesn't look elegant and feels quite long for string replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$str = '01234567890123456789';
$rep = array(array(3,3,'test'), array(8,2,'haha'));
$index = 0;
$ctr = 0;
$index_strlen = 0;
foreach($rep as $s)
{
   $index = $s[0]+$index_strlen;

   $str = substr_replace($str, $s[2], $index, $s[1]);

   $index_strlen += strlen($s[2]) - $s[1];
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: `$rep` is missing length of characters needs to be replaced. This only replaces 1 character for each `$rep`.

Comment: you set $repeat to number of repeats for each char

Comment: `$repeat = 1;` gets me `12test4567haha9123456789`. `$repeat = 2;` gets me `12test4567haha912test4567haha9`. And the number of characters needs to be replaced can be different for each `$rep`, not fixed.

Comment: hmm.. to be clear, '3' and '8' in `$rep` should be indices in `$str`, not substring to replace.

Comment: It is not. `array(3, 2, 'test')` means: starting from the third index as many as two characters, replace with 'test' (four characters). In this case, `strlen()` will increase by 2.

Comment: That means I would need to have `$rep` in a sorted order. Thanks!